# Registro de CSV se sube a MySQL con "?"

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo el problema que al subir un registro (o un buen) a MySQL desde CSV con PHP y AJAX, la celda inicial es decir columna A fila 1 (A1), al momento de cargar la información de la celda a la base de datos se le anexa un signo de interrogación (?) pero solo con esa celda ¿Alguien sabe cuál es el problema?
Anexo parte del código

```
 $file_data = fopen($_FILES["employee_file"]["tmp_name"], 'r');
 while($row = fgetcsv($file_data, 0, ",", "'")) {  
     $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $row[0]);
     $address = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $row[1]);
     $gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $row[2]);  
     $designation = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $row[3]);  
     $age = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $row[4]);  
     $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_employee (name, address, gender, designation, age) VALUES 
     ('$name', '$address', '$gender', '$designation', '$age')";
     mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
 }
```

Es la parte de inserción, lo demás es valiación de tipo CSV, y pues como explico es un volcado de CSV a BD-MySQL

Ejemplo final de volcado, como ven el registro 1 tiene un "?", estoy pensando en eliminar caracateres especiales antes de la insercción pero quiero ver que otra solución puede haber

```
1   ?Fulanito1  La Piedra 223   Hombre  Programador 99
2   Fulanito2   La Piedra 223   Hombre  Programadro 99
```

Comment: Comprueba la página de códigos del archivo, de la conexión a la base de datos `$connect` y la `collation` de la columna con el problema. Tiene pinta que alguna difiere. Por ejemplo, intenta ver que sucede cuando en el CSV hay acentos, a ver si tambien se almacenan dañados.

Answer (score 1):

Como comento masterguru, mi problema era de collation, corregí la tabla y base de datos desde el SGBD ¡Problema solucionado!